# How to stream from java browser applet to applet

Tags: java, applet, jmf

I want two applets..

1. Transmitter applet which transmit the user's screen+audio from mic to getParameter("IP") and getParameter("PORT"). transmition is done after user's click on a "transmit" button and approval.
2. Receiver applet which receives the transmission from getParameter("IP") and getParameter("PORT") and play it with volume,play/pause,full-screen controls. and can save the stream into mpeg file.

Can anyone suggest how to stream in java from applet to applet?

Thank You,
Ronak

Comment: *"applet to applet"*  Why an applet (for either of them)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Useed ROBOT Class and JMF..
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html
http://grack.com/downloads/school/enel619.10/report/java_media_framework.html